# Conditional column name in SQL where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

How should the below be handled in SQL? What would be the where clause?

```
select *
from tbl_A a
inner join tbl_B b on a.pid = b.pid
where #name# like '%@searchText%
```

But this column `#name#` is based on the condition - (if `pid` is null then use `a.pname` column else use `b.name`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use regular AND/OR logic...

```
select *
from tbl_A a
left join tbl_B b on a.pid = b.pid
where (a.pid is null and a.pname like '%' + @SearchText + '%')
or (a.pid is not null and b.pname like '%' + @SearchText + '%');
```

1. You'll be wanting to split the search text out as shown to add the wildcards.
2. You'll be wanting a left join is `pid` can be null i.e. there is no match.